# Commenting/ Excluding commands for Latex 2 HTML with Pandoc

Tags: pandoc, comments, latex2html

The Following Latex Item ends with the Runaway Argument, as apparently the begin/end soln need to be on separate lines.

What I am trying to test is if there is a way to steer out certain commands for different outputs. I have a really long beautiful Latex Document, with all the wonderful packages etc. Now unfortunately two packages which make the PDF really beautiful create big problems in the Pandoc-HTML part, and it would be then just convenient to edit out these parts for the compilation of the HTML. Like the \ref, which is another item Pandoc cannot properly deal with. Any idea on how to design such an inline comment out function?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{comment}
\includecomment{soln}
\title{ABC}
\author{ABC}
\begin{document}
\section{ABC}\label{se:ABC}
Let us go to section DEF 
\begin{soln}%I want this into one line begin ref end
\ref{se:DEF}
\end{soln}
\section{DEF}\label{se:DEF}
Let us go to section ABC 
\begin{soln} %I want this into one line begin ref end
\ref{se:ABC}
\end{soln}
\end{document}
```

Comment: your sample doesn't compile even with `pdflatex`. after putting `\begin{soln}..\end{soln}` on a separate lines, I can convert it to HTML using `make4ht`

Comment: Hi - that is the point. It does compile with splitting the lines out, but I want the inlines ... 

I want to see whether there is something that makes blablabla \command leftout \endcommand blablabla inline.

Comment: Ah, but that doesn't depend on Pandoc or anything, this is a feature that the `comment` package doesn't provide. You can try to contact the package author if it is even possible to use the environment inline. I suspect that it will be difficult, because he explicitly states that environment start and end needs to be on the their own lines, without any spaces in front of them.

Comment: Yes, I know, it is programmed that way. The todonotes has inline functionality, but that has then other major formatting issues.

Basically what I am trying to see if there is a way to feed the HTML of the same Latex I use for the PDF/Print edition and building in a switch that eliminates the parts of the Latex code that the HTML processing doesn't deal well with.